# Show that a function is a homeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R} ^2 \longrightarrow (0, \infty) \times \mathbb{R}$ be given by a formula:

$f(x,y)=(e^x, x-y)$

Show that it is a homeomorphism (in standard euclidean metric).

As I understand we have to check continuity ($f$ is continuous, since $f=(f_{1},f_{2}-f_{3})$, where $f_{1}=e^x$,  $f_{2}=x, f_{3}=y$ and every such a function is continuous. Is this reasoning valid?

Then we should show that it is a bijection (seems to be OK).

And finally propose a continuous inverse function. What kind of formula could describe it?

Comment: Hint: the 1st coord should have log x as its inverse

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE. One way to find the inverse function for some $y = f^{-1}(x)$ is first to switch the variables to $x = f(y)$, and then to do some algebra to get $y$ by itself. In a similar vein, we can start with
$$f^{-1}(x_1, x_2) = (y_1, y_2),$$
switch it around to
$$f(y_1, y_2) = (x_1, x_2),$$
and then do some algebra to get $y_1$ and $y_2$ by themselves again.

Explicitly, we're starting with
$$(e^{y_1}, y_1 - y_2) = (x_1, x_2), $$
and this leads to two equations in which you can get $y_1$ and $y_2$ in terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$.